# RFT 8.6 : Failed to enable Firefox31.4 ESR and IE11 browser with JRE 1.7 on Windows 7 Professional SP1 ( 64bit)

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, windows

I am trying to configure RFT 8.6 with the installed browsers but getting errors while doing it, below are the configurations details of my setup followed up with the error I am facing...

RFT 8.6 on Windows 7 Professional SP1 ( 64bit)
JRE : 1.7.0 (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\lib)

Browser: Firefox 31.4 ESR and IE11

Problem: 1. It is failing in diagnostic test while trying to test FF, below is content from "Details" tab

```
____________________________________________________________________________
Java Enabled
  Java Enabled In Browser = false
JVM Information
    JVM Version = Error
    JVM Vendor = Error
General Enablement Information
    Bootstrap Loaded = Error
    Java2TestDomainImplementation Loaded = Error
    HtmlTestDomainImplementation Loaded = Error
    HtmlTestDomainImplementation Name = Netscape
____________________________________________________________________________
```

Problem 2: It if failing to while trying to enable it from RFT > Enable environment', it is showing error message `' Failed to enable the browser. Browser location is c:\Program files\internet explorer'`

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to the latest fixpack of RFT 8.6 (8.6.0.9), then you don't need to enable the Firefox browser anymore and can skip that step.